# Testing HTMLMediaElement.play() in Angular 7, Jasmine, Karma, Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I am trying to create a test in Angular using Jasmine that should fit both conditions when `HTMLMediaElement.play()` promise is resolved and rejected. Trying to figure it out in the following way:

```
it('should start playing audio file', async(() => {
    new Audio('path/to/my.mp3').play().then(
        () => {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            expect(true).toBeFalsy('FROM RESOLVE');
        },
        () => {
            console.log('ERROR');
            expect(true).toBeFalsy('FROM REJECT');
        }
    );
}));
```

I can't understand why, when promise is rejected, everything is ok:

> ERROR (in console)
>   Expected true to be falsy 'FROM REJECT' (from Jasmine)

but when promise is resolved my test should also fail, but it passes (no errors from Jasmine) and I get the following in the console:

> SUCCESS
>   Unhandled Promise rejection: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out

Why is the `expect` not working when this promise resolves?

**UPDATE**

The following two examples did the trick (thanks to @quirimmo):

```
it('should start playing audio file', async () => {
    await new Audio('path/to/my.mp3').play().then(
        () => {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            expect(true).toBeFalsy('FROM RESOLVE');
        },
        () => {
            console.log('ERROR');
            expect(true).toBeFalsy('FROM REJECT');
        }
    );
});

it('should start playing audio file', (done) => {
    new Audio('path/to/my.mp3').play().then(
        () => {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            expect(true).toBeFalsy('FROM RESOLVE');
            done();
        },
        () => {
            console.log('ERROR');
            expect(true).toBeFalsy('FROM REJECT');
            done();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Use await or pass the done callback or return the promise. The issue is due to the fact that the test finishes before the then is resolved and the assertions are checked

Comment: @quirimmo thank you! I thought that `it('...', async(() => { ... }));` will wait till resolving / rejecting every promise inside the test. But it's not true, yes?

Comment: No problem :) . Exactly. You need to use the `await` too. Or the `done`. Or, as I usually prefer, directly return the promise from the test. In this way it will wait for it.